# review board didn't display repository after add

Tags: svn, amazon-ec2, review-board

I have started a review board on amazon ec2 and I can success log in as admin from my computer. And any other functions including add users, create group works well except add svn repository.
I have strict followed the instruction from the document. But I didn't see the repository I just added.
I have struggled in two days for this.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide more information about what you did (eg commands run), what you expected (eg files appearing in a particular directory) and what actually happened (eg listed directory but it was empty)? People may then be able to assist you. Oh, and what is a "review board", and which "document" did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact sequence of steps you followed and the exact message you got, it would be very difficult to answer this. Although, from my experience with review board, if you are unable to add a new repo, most likely it could be because of permission issues for the repo directory. Make sure that the user that is running review board has permissions to access the repo directory.